# "No suitable driver" error occurs in Springboot 2.4.3 but not 2.2.2 RELEASE

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, c3p0

I always got the "No suitable driver" error when I tried to connect to MySql (8.0.23) database. I specify the JDBC driver in `application.yml` file in my Springboot (2.4.3) application: https://github.com/aliensnoopy/crm/blob/6cd02d8042cf3aac275e39d642aec8dcaa9c85fb/src/main/resources/application.yml#L12

I can verify that my local MySql server is up and running and my password is correct since I can connect to the database from terminal.

However, after I change the springboot version from `2.4.3` to `2.2.2 RELEASE`, everything magically works! There must be some subtle differences between these two Springboot versions that make this happen, but I can't figure out yet.

I setup some breakpoints to try to debug why it doesn't work in SpringBoot 2.4.3, I find that when the server starts, the `user` and `password` cannot be read correct and thus they are both `null` as the screenshot shows:
[image]

And the `jdbcUrl` is also `null`:
[image]

So, I guess the datasource information I specified in `application.yml` may not be read correctly in `SpringBoot 2.4.3`. Is there any difference between `SpringBoot 2.4.3` and `SpringBoot 2.2.2 RELEASE` in reading `application.yml` file or initializing the database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the MySQL connector as a dependency to you boot maven or gradel file?

Comment: Yeah, added it in my pom.xml file: https://github.com/aliensnoopy/crm/blob/6cd02d8042cf3aac275e39d642aec8dcaa9c85fb/pom.xml#L58